# Run command A, then command B in Command Line

Tags: batch-file, command

I have a problem with a following command:

```
DSQUERY group -name "Marketing" | dsget group -members | 
DSGET user -email & DSMOD user -tel 00000000
```

What this is supposed to do is to list the email addresses of all the people in the Marketing group and modify their telephone number to 0000000

What it does it just stops after doing the first command and doesn't move forward.
At first I tried separating the last DSGET and DSMOD with |, but then it throwed me an error that the target object for this command has an incorrect format.

Thanks for help!
Bartosz

Comment: Sorry, that's not enough info for me...

Comment: Did you call the batch file `dsquery.*` or `dsget.*` ?  That error happens quite often, using the command name for the batch file name.

Comment: I didn't even make it to a batch file, that doesn't even work in the command line...

Answer (score 0):

```
DSQUERY group -name "Marketing" | dsget group -members | DSGET user -email & DSMOD user -tel 00000000
```

Comment: Seems to me it's exactly the same as I do... Which just stops after displaying emails and does not modify the telephone?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that both the last DSGET and the DSMOD need to consume the output of the first DSGET.

At this point, as I don't know what these command are or how to work with them, I can only suggest storing the output of the first DSGET in a temporary file, then feeding the file to the other DSGET and to the DSMOD individually, something like this:

```
DSQUERY group -name "Marketing" | dsget group -members >"%TEMP%\tmpresults"
DSGET user -email <"%TEMP%\tmpresults"
DSMOD user -tel 00000000 <"%TEMP%\tmpresults"
```